# Trouble installing scipy in virtualenv on a amazon ec2 linux micro instance

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, scipy, virtualenv

I have successfully installed `scipy` in the default python compiler on an amazon ec2 micro instance (Ubuntu 13.04). However i am not able to install `scipy` in a virtualenv.

`pip install scipy` ends with this error

```
scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.cxx: In function ‘void init_csr()’:

scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.cxx:73303:21: warning: variable ‘md’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/ubuntu/pnr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/ubuntu/pnr/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-t8Drvd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/ubuntu/pnr/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code -9 in /home/ubuntu/pnr/build/scipy
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/pnr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/home/ubuntu/pnr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    return command.main(args[1:], options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/pnr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 169, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Before anyone asks. `pip freeze` for default compiler returns

```
Cheetah==2.4.4
Landscape-Client==12.12
M2Crypto==0.21.1
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.0.0
PyYAML==3.10
Twisted-Core==12.3.0
Twisted-Names==12.3.0
Twisted-Web==12.3.0
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
boto==2.3.0
chardet==2.0.1
cloud-init==0.7.2
configobj==4.7.2
distribute==0.6.34
distro-info==0.10
euca2ools==2.1.1
numpy==1.7.1
oauth==1.0.1
paramiko==1.7.7.1
prettytable==0.6.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycrypto==2.6
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.8.0
pyserial==2.6
python-apt==0.8.8ubuntu6
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu1
requests==1.1.0
scipy==0.11.0
six==1.2.0
ssh-import-id==3.14
urllib3==1.5
virtualenv==1.10.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

`pip freeze` command for virtualenv returns

```
Cython==0.19.2
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.0.0.1
Flask-WTF==0.9.3
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
WTForms==1.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.4
argparse==1.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
itsdangerous==0.23
numpy==1.7.1
pymongo==2.6.2
requests==2.0.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: There must be other log entries, containing actual command being killed, can you provide them

Comment: @alko i have updated the error message

Comment: I have a feeling the error is caused due to insufficient memory in micro instance (512 MB).

Comment: I have sucessfully installed scipy on `ec2.micro` instance more than once.

Comment: @alko you installed it using pip?

Comment: yes, as all other packages. in fact it was smoother and faster than on ec2.small instances, since latter are 32bit and micros have 64bit arch

Answer (score 101, accepted):

One solution is to temporarily enable swap on your micro instance. As described at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance), enable 1gb swap via:

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Once swap is on, install scipy via pip:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev gfortran python-dev build-essential g++
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install scipy
```

Once scipy successfully installs, you can disable it via:

```
sudo swapoff /var/swap.1
sudo rm /var/swap.1
```

Comment: Works on DigitalOcean 512MB machine as well.

Comment: Also works on Google Compute Engine f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)

Comment: Doesn't work on my Debian VPS! Damn those traditionalists... :-(

Comment: Also works if with other packages that use scipy like statsmodels, if you install them in the middle

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me:

```
pip --no-cache-dir install scipy
```

See:

- [Memory error while using pip install Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466663/memory-error-while-using-pip-install-matplotlib)

  https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/9a23d4ed119327d3b823ec223aaead90964bac58/pip/basecommand.py#L56-L63
- https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/28cca11e284b37cc2c7977fd25be6f494adda9d3/src/pip/_internal/download.py#L359-L367

**note:**

- works for other service providers, hardware, VMs, and containers.
- if RAM allocation size of 1GB
- just calculate the diff between the cached directory memory usage and available ram

Comment: This worked like a charm. I was able to install it on t2 instance. Easily fits into my code pipeline.

Comment: Great solution, solved the error on my t2.micro AWS instance.

Comment: Much better solution than the one accepted, which is now a bit old.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, 512MB is not enough for compiling that C++ file.

Your best option is to build Scipy as a binary package (bdist, or [eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs), or, more modern [wheels](https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) e.g. via `python setupegg.py bdist_egg` on a different machine with compatible environment. For instance, use a similar Linux version to the EC2 instance in a virtual machine.

In general, it's good to remember that when `pip` installs packages, it compiles source files. If the package is not tiny, this is inefficient and it's better to use binary packages. The `wheel` package format is supposed to play well together with pip.

Comment: not easy to find a same binary egg as for ec2.micro. any way to set compiling parameter?

Answer (score 2):

for me the error was slightly different.

```
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

the BLAS environment variable.

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/kdixit/pyvirt/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/kdixit/pyvirt/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n
```

Thus I had to install

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
```

and then it worked.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu image - seemed that the package had been renamed from `libatlas3-base-dev` to the same minus the 3.

Comment: For me (on my local machine) the error was: `error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found`. I had installed previously a precompiled version of scipy , so I didn't check the package _gfortran_ was installed. The moral is: double check you have all of the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an out of virtual memory error during the `scipy` compilation on a `t2.micro`, I think `numpy` compiled just fine. Anyway, I guess that **Dolan Antenucci**'s answer would fix my issue, but instead I went another route, a compromise, which does work.

I'm running an `Ubuntu` instance so keep that in mind.

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-scipy && echo -e "\nok, installed python-scipy, continuing...\n"

# add scipy to the venv
mkdir ~/venv_PROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/* ~/venv_PROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/

# add numpy to the venv
mkdir ~/venv_PROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/* ~/venv_PROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/

# add PIL to the venv
mkdir ~/venv_PROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/* ~/venv_PROJECT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/
```

The compromise is that you won't be able to use diferent versions among different virtual environments and you're tied to the version in the repo.

A word of warning:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.13.3'

>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.8.2'

>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image.VERSION
'1.1.7'
```