# anyone has install scipy on aws free tier?

Tags: python, scipy

I've got problem when pip install scipy on aws micro instance, which has only 512 MB memory.
lapack-devel, blas-devel, and numpy already installed.
some one said the memory is too small to build c++ when install scipy.
if anyone succeeded or has similar binary scipy install image, please lend a hand.

image:
Linux ip-172-31-16-186 3.4.43-43.43.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 6 18:04:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

last building log:

```
scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.cxx: In function ‘void init_csr()’:
scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.cxx:73303:21: warning: variable ‘md’ set but not used [-
Wunused-but-set-variable]
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:115706: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
error: Command "g++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -       fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-    size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/home/ec2-user/  env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c scipy/sparse/sparsetools/ csr_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.o" failed with exit status 4
```

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: sorry for the late, just updated.

Comment: I got this working by temporarily enabling swap. I detailed this process on a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20890162/318870

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble installing scipy in virtualenv on a amazon ec2 linux micro instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595944/trouble-installing-scipy-in-virtualenv-on-a-amazon-ec2-linux-micro-instance)