# PIP Install Numpy throws an error "ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe2"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pip

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu on a freshly built computer. I just installed python-pip using apt-get. Now when I try to pip install Numpy and Pandas, it gives the following error.

I've seen this error mentioned in quite a few places on SO and Google, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Some people mention it's a bug, some threads are just dead... What's going on?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Are there non-ASCII characters in your hostname, home directory, &c.? Does setting `LC_ALL=C` make any difference?

Comment: While this post is aimed at Amazon's EC2, it seems to be the same problem, and I find the answers more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595944/trouble-installing-scipy-in-virtualenv-on-a-amazon-ec2-linux-micro-instance

Comment: I still do have a problem with the installation even though i have gotten numpy. Is there anyone else that have this problem?

Comment: As OP, and 3 years later, I can say I have solved this by migrating to Haskell ;)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had this exact problem recently and used

```
apt-get install python-numpy
```

This adds numpy to your system python interpreter.  I may have had to do the same for matplotlib.  To use in a virtualenv, you have to create your environment using the

```
--system-site-packages
```

option

http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: Thanks! Also, I found that if python-dev doesn't come stock on the computer, you need that too

Comment: Yeah. I remember that now.. Good catch.

Comment: You don't need to recreate your `virtualenv`, you can modify an existing one with `virtualenv VIRTUALENV_DIR --system-site-packages`.

Comment: this fixed the same error I had with pip install scipy, thanks

Comment: Had same issue on Ubuntu server 14.02. `sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev` solved the issue.

Comment: This solves the problem but I think you should at least mention you are making (all) system packages available, so the point of using virtualenv is partially defeated...

Answer (score 37):

For me @Charles Duffy comment solved it.
Put this in your env:

`LC_ALL=C`

You can add it to your .bashrc with a line like this:

`export LC_ALL=C`

But take in care that you'll affect all other programs. So you may want to use it just for the pip run:

`$ LC_ALL=C pip install ...`

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Using `--system-site-packages` was not an option for me.

Comment: a better wording for you answer would be: add "export LC_ALL=C" to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: @GilHiram Depends on your shell type you may have to set up this env variable in other places. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/what-is-the-difference-between-interactive-shells-login-shells-non-login-shell

Comment: The install didn't work for me both within, and outside a virtualenv so using `--system-site-packages` was not the right answer. I got it to work inside a virtualenv with `LC_ALL=C pip install ...`.

Comment: what does `export LC_ALL=C` *mean* / do ?

Comment: @javadba It forces applications to use the default language for output, and forces sorting to be bytewise.

Answer (score 13):

Try updating pip:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: This worked for me on debian jessie inside of a venv.

Answer (score 7):

I had that problem with matplotlib package.
I had to execute:

```
export LC_ALL=C
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 5):

For me this was solved by ignoring a (presumably) corrupted cache with

```
pip install --no-cache-dir ...
```

as described here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2674

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when running `pip install pandas` and it was due to a memory shortage.  I increased the memory in my virtual machine to 4G and that fixed things.

Comment: Same here. Upgraded VM instance from 1 to a 2 gig RAM temporarily while installing.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

and

```
export LC_ALL=C
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I stumbled upon the same problem
This solved it for me:

```
              echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc
              echo 'export LANGUAGE=en_US:en' >> ~/.bashrc
              echo 'export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.bashrc
              sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
```

Note,

I already had python-numpy and python-dev installed. Even this may be causing a problem on your system.
You can also export LC_ALL=C instead of en_US.UTF-8(or any other language)

Answer (score 3):

When running in a docker container, this fixed it for me (on the project django-postgrespool, but this should also work here).

```
# Set the locale
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406007/1876203

Comment: `locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` worked for me as well! Or `RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` in Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

In 'site-packages' directory, make 'sitecustomize.py' like this

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Now you can get the file 'pip.log'

Comment: This is only an indirect answer, but it teaches something and does not deserve to be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` .
It worked out for me and same can be used for scipy,pandas etc by replacing them in place of numpy. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

@OSX Users: Add the following lines to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Execute the scripts using
    `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pip version of numpy, you can build the dependencies for the package and then install it using pip

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-numpy
pip install numpy
```

This should install everything needed at system level to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on a Jetson TK1 with Ubuntu.

Works fine with `apt-get install python-pandas`

Answer (score 0):

So many answers and none worked for me even though some clearly worked for other people.  But I then figured out what my problem was, so I'll just add it to the collection:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
# enable the "en-US.UTF-8" locale
# when asked for a default, no need to define one
```

The thing is, I was working inside a Debian Stretch linux container that happened to not have any UTF-8 locales installed, probably because I downloaded a minimal stock image.  With this UTF-8 locale now installed, pip properly installed numpy and other packages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had just installed Python from source (on a remote machine where I am not `sudo`).  For whatever reason, `pip` was on some really old version.  So after:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I was able to install `numpy` and everything I wanted without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar problem. I tried:

```
export LC_ALL=C
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

But it did not solve the problem, but another error came up:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rollback'

Then I tried:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Then the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting my regional settings in my machine to the expected one solved my problem. For me the problem started when I switched my language settings to English(India). I had to switch it back to English(Great Britain).