# How can I get the stable version of numpy for PyPy?

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I've downloaded PyPy portable version from the link https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy-2.4.0-src.tar.bz2 and I've installed numpy for PyPy with the command `pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git`

Installing was successfull, but I can't use `numpy.min` function like this.

```
>>>> numpy.min([1,2,3])    
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: expected integer, got NoneType object
```

so, I've run `numpy.test()` and the result is

```
FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=5, SKIP=24, errors=886, failures=152)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=3367 errors=886 failures=152>
```

It seems to be unstable version of numpy that I installed. How can I get the stable version of numpy for PyPy?

Also I tried just `pip install numpy` (not `pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git`)

However, I've faced another problem discussed in the link [PIP Install Numpy throws an error "ascii codec can't decode byte 0xe2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473681/pip-install-numpy-throws-an-error-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2)

The answer is using `apt-get` for installing numpy but, this answer is just for CPython. is there a good solution for PyPy?

Comment: Are you sure that there's a `numpy` version which works with `pypy` yet? The last `pypy` blog post about it I could find is from April and it still seems work in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just downloaded Pypy 2.4 and its numpy (via the git install).  Looks like the `ufunc` functionality has a bug or is just incomplete.

```
x = numpy.arange(10)
x.sum()  # 45
x.min()  # 0
numpy.min(x)  # TypeError: expected integer, got NoneType object
numpy.sum(x)  # same error
```

but if I give it an `out` attribute these `ufunc` versions work (sortof)

```
numpy.sum(x, out=1)  # returns 45
numpy.min(x, out=1)  # returns 0
numpy.min(x, out=None)  # gets the above error
```

But it does not return a value in the `out` parameter

```
y = 0
numpy.sum(x, out=y)  # returns 45, but does not change y
```

Regular `numpy` would object about `y` not being an array (or having the wrong dimensions).

---

`np.min(x)` is that same as `np.core.umath.minimum.reduce(x,None,None,None)`, where the `reduce` arguments are `(variable, axis, dtype, out)`.  `np.core.umath.minimum.reduce(x)` works fine.

`np.core.umath.add.accumulate` works as expected with respect to the `out` argument, so the problem seems to be isolated to the `reduce`.

If you install with git clone you get the full repository on your machine, which you can explore.  That info is also available online.  I'm still trying to figure out where the ufunc reduce is defined, and whether it was fully functional or not.  This module is still very much in the development stage.

---

http://buildbot.pypy.org/numpy-status/latest.html is a numpy status table.  It references a `pypy/module/micronumpy` directory.  I haven't figured out how this relates to the https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git repository (on the download page).  I can find the `ufunc.reduce` code in the `micronumpy` tree, but not in the `numpy.git` tree.

---

In `core/_methods.py`, `sum` is defined as a call to `add.reduce`.  `min` and `max` similarly.  Keyword parameters become positional ones.

```
def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
    return um.add.reduce(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
```

But it looks like the order of those parameters is wrong.  `out` is the 4th, but when I try `add.reduce` directly, I have to make the 6th.

```
>>>> x
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.]])
>>>> y=np.zeros((2,))
>>>> np.add.reduce(x, 0, float, False, False, y)
array([ 6.,  9.])
# reduce(a, axis, dtype, ?, keepdims, out)
```

I saw in passing that there is a `commit` in the `micronumpy` tree dealing with a wrong parameter order for `reduce`.  That may be fixing this error.

In regular `numpy` the `sum` call is:

```
um.add.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

which works fine.  Apparently someone was trying to squeeze out a bit of performance by minimizing keyword parameters.

`module/micronumpy/ufuncs.py` defines `reduce` as:

```
reduce(self, space, w_obj, w_axis, keepdims=False, out=None, dtype=None,
    cumulative=False)
```