# Upgrading pandas on linux

Tags: python, linux, pandas

So, Currently I have `Python 2.7.6` in my linux system and pandas version `'0.13.1'` so I was using dt accesor in my code which wasnt working.After some google I came to know it requires higher version of pandas. I tried a couple of things. It is giving me warning `#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \` . Any help on this how can I upgrade this?

Comment: use `pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: @shivsn I did that only it first downloads `Downloading pandas-0.18.1.tar.gz (7.3MB): `then it donloads`Downloading numpy-1.11.1.zip (4.7MB):` and then the warning as in question. and ultimately teminates on `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @shivsn `no such option: --no-cache-dir`

Comment: @shivsn already did that same problem

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473681/pip-install-numpy-throws-an-error-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2) question.

Comment: for full process < https://pastee.org/3dxcw  >

Comment: @shivsn thanx for your effort but non of the option worked.

Comment: If you find a solution post it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [log](https://pastee.org/3dxcw), the two interesting lines are

> copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/_period.so -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas
>
> error: could not delete '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/_period.so': Permission denied

The problem is obvious: You have a system version of pandas installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7`, and an old versions of pandas installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`. `/usr/local/bin` is a system-wide directory, so you need superuser rights to write to it. However, your user does not have these rights.

There are a number of options to rectify the problem:

1. Use a virtualenv or another way of installing panda in a local directory. In order to avoid confusion, it may be a good idea to remove the system-wide installations in `/usr/local/` and the one in `/usr/lib`.
2. Call pip install with the `--user` option to install pandas for your current user. Again, it depends on your system setup, but it may be a good idea to remove the system-wide installations.
3. Update the system-wide pip installation. You'll need superuser rights (typically acquired by prefixing the command with `sudo`, as in `sudo pip install -U pandas`). It may be a good idea to remove the OS version.
4. Find a way to update the OS version (in `/usr/lib`). Again, remove all others.

To remove the installation in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pandas/`, run `sudo pip uninstall pandas` or remove the directory outright.

It depends on the linux distribution how you get rid of your operating system version. In most releases, something along the lines of `sudo apt-get remove -y python-pandas` should work.

Everything before these messages is just warnings. The `UnicodeDecodeError` is a red herring, since it only *occurs* after the installation has failed.

To find out which pandas version you are using, you can examine the Python path (`print(sys.path)`) or more cleverly, simply run

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__file__)
```

Comment: I already tried `sudo pip install -U pandas` this is what happens < https://pastee.org/xm2mn > .

Comment: virtualenv i dont want to use . Can it be upgraded for all of the user ?

Comment: @Danish If you tried something already, please do include (a link to) these logs in the question! It sucks to have to guess stuff and play ping pong. In a similar vein, feel free to be a little bit more precise about your system, For instance, what Linux distribution are you running? What CPU architecture? Unless your system's configuration is a state secret (and then you probably shouldn't post on stackoverflow in the first place), I fail to comprehend why one would not include as much information as possible in a question. Alright, I have updated my answer based on the new log.