# Bazel language and locale environment

Tags: linux, bazel

I've come across a python error [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473681/pip-install-numpy-throws-an-error-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2) while running `genrule`s in my bazel setup.

The root cause of this error is that certain language environment variables are not set as expected, so files aren't being read with the correct encoding.

Setting

```
build --action_env="LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
run --action_env="LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
test --action_env="LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
```

in my `.bazelrc` is a workaround, but feels somewhat hacky. What is the best way to configure bazel's language/locale settings for genrules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--action_dev`/`--test_env` is the only way to pass in an environment variable. 
It can be specified in `.bazelrc` or be set as an argument to `bazel` command.

Alternatively, if you only need to set an env variable for a specific `genrule`, you can do that explicitly in your `genrule`. Note `FOO=bar` in `cmd`:

```
genrule(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [],
    outs = ["foo.h"],
    cmd = "FOO=bar ./$(location create_foo.pl) > \"$@\"",
    tools = ["create_foo.pl"],
)
```