# installing matplotlib on virtualenv failing with `freetype cannot be built`

Tags: python, matplotlib, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a flask app on EC2, using virtualenv. I've created a virtualenv using `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python venv` and activated it using `source venv/bin/activate`.
Then I cloned my github flask repo, and ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, I'm getting an error when installing `matplotlib`.

```
File "/home/ec2-user/network-visualizer/venv/lib/python2.6/site-
packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 81, in dumps
      ).encode("utf8"),
  MemoryError
```

I've googled around and tried `pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466663/memory-error-while-using-pip-install-matplotlib) but this time, I'm seeing

```
    ================================================================
============

                            * The following required packages can no
t be built:

                            * freetype

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /
tmp/pip-build-3dMFaT/matplotlib
```

I then ran `sudo yum install freetype` and got

```
Package freetype-2.3.11-15.14.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and lat
est version
Nothing to do
```

I'm stuck now... What should I need to install additionally to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the freetype development tools as well. I think that it's freetype-devel or libfreetype.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
sudo yum install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the following:

```
sudo apt install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
```

That should solve the problem