# aws ec2 error installing matplotlib

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a script on an ec2 instance which requires **matplotlib** and apparently it is not installed by default. So I am trying to do it

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```

as you can see in the image, I get this error:
[image]

and here is the text version:

```
Collecting matplotlib   Downloading matplotlib-2.0.0.tar.gz (53.2MB)
    99% |████████████████████████████████| 53.2MB 24.0MB/s eta 0:00:01  Exception:   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 345, in prepare_files
      functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 290, in _walk_req_to_install
      more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 487, in _prepare_file
      download_dir, do_download, session=self.session,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 827, in unpack_url
      session,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 673, in unpack_http_url
      from_path, content_type = _download_http_url(link, session, temp_dir)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 888, in _download_http_url
      _download_url(resp, link, content_file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 621, in _download_url
      for chunk in progress_indicator(resp_read(4096), 4096):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 133, in iter
      for x in it:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 586, in resp_read
      decode_content=False):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 273, in stream
      data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 203, in read
      data = self._fp.read(amt)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 54, in read
      self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 224, in cache_response
      self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 81, in dumps
      ).encode("utf8"),   MemoryError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory error while using pip install Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466663/memory-error-while-using-pip-install-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a lower tier of the EC2 instance, the memory allocated to the instance might not be sufficient to used to compile the mathplot.

If you are on a lower tier ec2 instance, you may consider to switch on swap. The following information was summarized from digitalocean website.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

We can see if the system has any configured swap by typing:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

Check current swap usage:

```
free -m
```

If it shows Swap: 0 0 0 that means there is no Swap
       total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3953        154       3799          0          8         83
-/+ buffers/cache:         62       3890
Swap:            0          0          0

Check space size

```
df -h
```

Make sure you have sufficient space and create:

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile
```

Verify space information:

```
ls -lh /swapfile
```

Return result of above command:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root **2.0G** Apr 28 17:19 /swapfile
```

Enabling the Swap File

```
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
```

Verify that the file has the correct permissions by typing:

```
ls -lh /swapfile
```

Setup swap space:

```
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

Use the swap space:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Check the procedure is correct:

```
sudo swapon -s
```

Check free space:

```
free -m
```

The Swap should have indicated more than 0 in total field.

Make the Swap File Permanent:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

At the end of the file key in :

```
/swapfile   none    swap    sw    0   0
```

After complete the above steps, you may consider to use yum install to install python-matplotlib:

```
sudo yum install python-matplotlib
```