# Installing Apache Airflow on Amazon Lightsail Instance

Tags: memory, installation, instance, airflow, amazon-lightsail

So i figured out the basics of Apache Airflow and I can run dags/tasks on my computer (so sleek!). However, I want to be able to have these run when my computer's off - so I bought a $5/month Lightsail instance and tried to install Airflow on there `pip install airflow`.

I keep getting the attached output. It seems as though there isn't enough memory on the instance to finish the command or something but I feel like if that were true, it would output an error message...

Thoughts?

[image: screenshot: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to my own question. I tried out the solution provided for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466663/memory-error-while-using-pip-install-matplotlib) question, and it worked:

First - I created a virtual environment and entered it by typing these commands into the command line:

`virtualenv my-env`,
`source my-venv/bin/activate`

Second - Once in the virtual environment, instead of inputing `pip install airflow`, I input `pip --no-cache-dir install airflow`. This worked to avoid the memory error!

Comment: Are you running webserver on lightsail as well? I’m see it too underpowered for my use. Have moved to EC2.