# Why R put downloaded packages in temp folder?

Tags: r, installation

When I download some external libraries in R using `install.packages("package")`
then package is placed in `R\Library` in my installation directory but I get additional message on my console that

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGcPSi1\downloaded_packages
```

Why R is putting binary package in `Temp` and are the packages in Temp are different from my `R\Library\package` ?

Comment: First comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312901/r-keeps-downloading-packages-to-tmp-directory) (I think)

Comment: @Richard I understood the reason behind it thanks :)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707941/how-do-i-change-the-default-library-path-for-r-packages