# R "killed" when running install.packages('ANY', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')

Tags: r, linux, amazon-ec2

I have an amazon linux ami on EC2 with R installed, but I can't seem to install any packages. I've googled for hours to no avail. Here's what I'm seeing:

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Killed
```

Things I've tried

- allow all traffic from all locations
- ran chmod 777 -R on R directory (included library dir)
- chown current_user -R on R directory (included library dir)
- tried a couple of different repos in install.packages()
- tried this on >5 major packages ; all packages are failing

If there's anything I should try, please let me know via comments and I'll update here. I've googled for hours to no avail. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not enough memory available? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21837457/3710546

Comment: Yes! You're right. 141mb available. I'm such a newb. Thank you. I didn't even think of that.