# How to install lxml on Amazon EC2 for Python 3.4

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, lxml, python-3.4

After I finally got lxml installed on my computer by downloading the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, I thought my lxml installation problems were behind me. But, clearly I was very wrong. It does not seem to be any easier on the EC2 platform. I have tried just about every command I can think of—sudo pip3/pip3.4/pip-3.4/easy_install-3.4 lxml/lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win32.whl/lxml-3.5.0-cp34-none-win32.whl, STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip3/pip3.4/pip-3.4/easyinstall-3.4 install lxml. I keep getting the `Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?` error message.
I have tried to install these libraries too, but so far not successfully. Any help with installing either lxml or the dependent libraries would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was eventually able to install libxml2 by executing the following procedure:

Download the tar.gz. file from http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.7/general/libxml2.html, transfer it to the EC2 instance, and run `tar -zxvf libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz` from the directory in which the file is located.
Run `sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python34-devel`. (The reason why I was unable to install these packages at first was that I used the omnipresent “-dev” wording, which did not work in this particular setup.)
From the libxml2-2.9.2 folder (as per the instructions at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.7/general/libxml2.html) run

```
    sed \
  -e /xmlInitializeCatalog/d \
  -e 's/((ent->checked =.*&&/(((ent->checked == 0) ||\
          ((ent->children == NULL) \&\& (ctxt->options \& XML_PARSE_NOENT))) \&\&/' \
  -i parser.c
```

,

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static --with-history --with-python=/usr/bin/python3 && make
```

, and

```
make install
```

Then . . . , when I finally ran `sudo easy_install-3.4 lxml`, guess what . . . ;  yes, the instance ran out of memory. So, I had to apply the following fix from [How do you add swap to an EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance):

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

After that, it took quite a while to install using `sudo easy_install-3.4 lxml`, but it worked.

Comment: I had a similar problem with same error message when trying to install lxml in an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03. In my case, the problem was that GCC was not installed. Doing `sudo yum install gcc` solved it. The error message asking if libxml2 is installed is very misleading.