# Node.js process getting killed on aws instances

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services

We are trying to deploy one of our node js applications(AngularJS/NodeJS tech stack) to Production environment. Randomly, some of the ec2 instances just goes down as node process is getting killed. But no application/system level error messages are getting logged. We are unable to replicate this issue in local/dev/it environments. Has anyone faced something similar? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you starting the NodeJS processes? You probably need to look into using a service like Forever: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: We are starting node js server using nohup command in the background.

Comment: that won't restart the Node process if an exception causes the process to exit. You need to just install Forever and use that.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior. Nodejs process randomly disappears, nothing in the log. Wonder if aws is the culprit...

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, just in case someone else run into the same problem. 
Most probably is that your a running out of memory, as explained [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/268288/most-long-running-commands-instantly-killed-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-10-04) You can verify with **dmesg** command (linux). To fix it you can add more memory or add a swap volume. 
One way is following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance):

```
sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap.1
sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
// enable after reboot
/var/swap.1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score -2):

By default, nodejs application would be stopped when no client connect to it, you could use some tools like `forever` to keep your nodejs app running