# I am using T2.micro ec2 Instance. It goes out of memory and kills the process and it shows 1/2 checks

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Here is my log :-

```
[1301334.004840] Out of memory: Killed process 155761 (mysqld) total-vm:1298812kB, anon-rss:432376kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:113 pgtables:1144kB oom_score_adj:0
[1302863.154766] Out of memory: Killed process 156184 (mysqld) total-vm:1300248kB, anon-rss:426200kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:113 pgtables:1176kB oom_score_adj:0
[1312609.442638] Out of memory: Killed process 156772 (mysqld) total-vm:1357840kB, anon-rss:469212kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:113 pgtables:1268kB oom_score_adj:0
```

For every 1 week, it is showing 1/2 check, and when I reboot my ec2 instance and everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me how to clear this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your server is running out of memory and as a result the kernel is killing processes to reclaim memory. Otherwise it would crash.

Your options are:

1. Enable swap file. Expect degraded performance (but it may be perfectly acceptable for you). See this answer: [How do you add swap to an EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance)
2. Upgrade to an instance with more memory. Expect a higher bill. This may not be an option if you want to use the free tier.