# Repeatedly db connection error on Aws Ec2 Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried this solution for now [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11830996/6100304) and now the error is removed. But it happens often.

Can anyone guide me what is the actual issue and its permanent solution?

I read somewhere that it happens when your server gets down due to load. Is it so?

If it is then what is the best technique to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you mentioned is the correct answer. It will might work permanently.